# How does GHCi ":browse" imported modules?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am working on generating codes, for which I need to know some information of other modules.

If I had the source of that module, haskell-src-exts is a way to go.

But what if I do not have the source? I see GHCi do something like this, but could not figure out what is the key.

TemplateHaskell's reifyModule only gives module relationships. Did I miss anything? Or there are other ways to go?

Comment: You will likely need to poke around in [the GHC API](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc), though I don't have enough experience with it to write a proper answer.

Comment: `:browse` uses the .hi files that are part of the package. Not nearly a complete answer, but at least a place to start looking.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks. That is something quite new to me....

Comment: @Carl Thanks. I saw something. Maybe suits me.

Comment: @Magicloud Are the other modules compiling? If so, this is quite simple with the GHC API: use `depanal` to compute the `ModuleGraph`, then look at the `ms_textual_imps` field of the `ModSummary`'s in that graph.